# How to set buttons as child layout in expandable listview instead of string

Tags: android, listview

I followed this tutorial http://www.androidhive.info/2013/07/android-expandable-list-view-tutorial/. In that tutorial the child layout set as string format but here I need to set **layout** directly instead of creating a string.

Here is my child layout code, that have Three buttons **Yes, No, Maybe** and a **Checkbox**.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/hidden"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="-270dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingTop="1dp"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:weightSum="3">


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/yesButton"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@color/lightgray"
        android:text="Yes"
        android:textColor="@color/black"></Button>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/noButton"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@color/lightgray"
        android:text="No"
        android:textColor="@color/black"></Button>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonMayBe"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@color/lightgray"
        android:text="Maybe"
        android:textColor="@color/black"></Button>


    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/invitationCheckBox"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/check_box_width"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:button="@drawable/selector"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:scaleX="0.5"
        android:scaleY="0.5" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: inflate this layout in getchildview().

Comment: can you please add the code ..

Answer (score 0):

Expandable listview adpater

```
public class ExpandableAdapter  extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

private Context _context;
ArrayList<Group> list;

public ExpandableAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Group> list) {
    this._context = context;
   this.list = list;
}

@Override
public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosititon) {
    return list.get(groupPosition).getMembers().get(childPosititon);

}

@Override
public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return childPosition;
}

@Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
                         boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {



    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.expand_child, null);
    }

    TextView txtListChild = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text1);

    txtListChild.setText(list.get(groupPosition).getMembers().get(childPosition).getName());
    return convertView;
}

@Override
public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
     return list.get(groupPosition).getMembers().size();
}

@Override
public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
     return list.get(groupPosition);
}

@Override
public int getGroupCount() {
     return list.size();
}

@Override
public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
    return groupPosition;
}

@Override
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
                         View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = infalInflater.inflate(android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_2, null);
    }

    TextView lblListHeader = (TextView) convertView
            .findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
    lblListHeader.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
    lblListHeader.setText(list.get(groupPosition).getGroupName());

    return convertView;
}

@Override
public boolean hasStableIds() {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return true;
}
```

}